# Have these (extremely simple) classes of algebraic structures been considered in the literature? If so, what are they called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, graph-theory, terminology

> **Questions.** Have the following kinds algebraic structures been considered in the abstract algebra literature etc.? If so, what are they really called? (I have used made-up terminology for the sake of the question.)

- A *woodland* is a set equipped with an $n$-ary operation $f_n$ for each integer $n \geq 0$. (Observe that every woodland has a distinguished element corresponding to the case $n=0$).
- A *jungle* is a woodland such that we can permute the arguments of $f_n$ willy-nilly. In particular, $(X,f_*)$ is a *jungle* iff for all integers $n \geq 0$ and all permutations $\pi$ of $\{0,\ldots,n-1\},$ it holds that $f_n(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}) = f_n(x_{\pi(0)},\ldots,x_{\pi(n-1)}).$

> **Motivation.** The [rooted trees](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootedTree.html) of graph theory form a jungle in an obvious way, and this is (isomorphic to) the [initial](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+object) jungle. Similarly, the ordered rooted trees form a woodland in an obvious way; and, this is the initial woodland.

Comment: This seems like a generalization of Boolean funcitons for a woodland. And symmetric Boolean functions for the second? No?

Comment: @amcalde, I'm not really seeing the connection. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Well a Boolean function takes $n$ arguments from the set $X = \{0,1\}$ and returns either $1$ or $0$ so from what I understand, it's like your woodland. $f: X^n \rightarrow X$. Except that your woodland seems to have some particular Boolean function picked out for each $n$.

Comment: So, for example the majority vote function on $X$ is a woodland because for any $n$ inputs the function $f_n$ is given as the majority vote on $n$ bits. (Of course you'd have to define what happens when $n$ is even and there is a tie.)

Comment: @amcalde, true. Nice observation. **Edit** actually I'm not quite sure how to make majority vote into a woodland. We have a majority vote function $B^n \rightarrow B$ for $n$ odd only, I think...

Comment: Well, there is supposed to be only one $f_n:X^n\to X$ in this structure. But I think the real problem is that there really isn't any conditions on these functions (except symmetry in the jungle) which means that it probably covers *too* many algebras. For example, any algebra with a unary and binary operation can be made into a woodland, with commutativity and associativity implying it would be a jungle.

Comment: Basically, if there are multiple operators and no relations between them, we really can only study one operator at a time - they do not interact. Imagine a ring without the distributive law.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to study objects with multiple operations unless there is a relationship between the various operations.  Otherwise you would just study each operation independently.  There is something called an Operad, which is much more complicated, but bears some similarity to the kind of objects you are talking about.

Comment: @goblin, Just say that $1$ wins on ties. Then this modified MAJ function is a woodland. Actually it's a jungle since it's all symmetric. Another jungle I can immediately think of is the popcount function mod 2. (Add up the number of ones mod 2 for any Boolean input).

Comment: @amcalde But we could really choose, for each $n$, any function  $f_n:X^n/S_n\to X$. Lacking any logical relationship between the operators, this is just a random collection of functions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, you're right, of course. I guess such structures aren't very interesting beyond the free algebra monad they define.

Comment: That free algebra has an interesting additional unary function which maps a rooted tree to the merger of the child trees (so it takes the tree, and identifies the root node with all of its children, yielding a new rooted tree.) Then the algebra has some interesting relationships.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I think I understand what you mean. Syntactically, we're flattening things. So $((x,y),(x,x,y))$ becomes $(x,y,x,x,y)$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes. If that unary function is $T$ (for truncate) then $Tf_1$ is the identity, $Tf_n(u_1,\dots,u_n)=Tf_2(u_1,Tf_{n-1}(u_2,\dots,u_n))$. Lots more relationships. Basically $Tf_n$ could be defined in terms of $Tf_2$ ultimately, and $Tf_2$ would be associative.

Comment: Even more interesting: $f_{m+n}(u_1,\dots,u_m,v_1,\dots,v_n)=T(f_2(f_m(u_1,\dots,u_m),f_n(v_1,\dots,v_n)))$. This would mean every $f_n$ can be defined in terms of $f_1,f_2,$ and $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "woodland" would be an algebra over the free nonsymmetric operad $W$ with one generating operation in each arity $n \ge 0$ and no relations. Similarly a "jungle" would be an algebra over the free symmetric operad $J$ with one generating operation in each arity $n \ge 0$ and $\Sigma_n$ acts trivially on the $n$th generating operation. Trees appear naturally because this is what operads are built on. It seems to me that the set of (resp. ordered) rooted trees is in fact the free $W$-algebra (resp. $J$-algebra) over the empty set (the initial set), which explains why they're initial in their category of algebras.

I don't believe these things have been studied on their own, as they have very little structure; consider that a magma is a woodland where all the $f_n$ are trivial for $n \neq 2$, and magmas aren't particularly studied. They're more of an intermediary technical tool.

One (rather silly) thing I can say is that if you consider a linear version of this and remove the operations in arity $0$ and $1$, then the first one is the ungraded underlying operad of the dg-operad $A_\infty$ controlling homotopy associative algebras (it would have $\operatorname{deg} f_n = n - 2$ and a differential $\partial(f_n)$ that I don't want to write down). I guess you can relate the second one to some shifted version of $L_\infty$. I doubt this is what you had in mind though.

Comment: If you decide that $f_n(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, f_0) = f_{n-1}(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1})$ (as suggested in the comments, I didn't read them all), then the operad starts looking quite different.